# Multiple goals tracked per session for unique URL?

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

For [zaza.rocks](https://zaza.rocks) I wonder if a unique visitor that completes 2 goals (for instance "create bag") in one session is counted as 2 goals?

Note: each time a visitor creates a new bag a new url is provided.

I know that under normal circumstances one goal is tracked per session. But [this](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2679221?hl=en) got me thinking: "One session can have one goal completion for each configured goal. So, the total can be up to 20 per session."

Answer (score 0):

20 is the maximum number of goals that you can configure in a view.

Each goal can only be activated once per session.

So if 20 goals are configured in a view and a user in a session activates all goals (one or more times), 20 goals will be counted for that session (one for each type).

Comment: Oke, if I understand correctly it would go like this. 

If a new or returning visitor creates 3 bags within one session.  It wil be measured as 1 created bag or 1 goal completion for that specific session.

Comment: Yes, that's right. The same goal, if activated several times in a session, is counted only once for that session.